# Add link to main page on grappelli admin

Tags: django, django-grappelli

Is there a simple way to add a link back to the main site when using the grappelli admin interface with django?

So when the user goes into the admin interface at

```
http://myurl/admin/
```

I'd like a link somewhere back to

```
http://myurl/
```

for the main site.

The only way I can see of doing this is to edit the grappelli templates, which feels very hacky for such a simple task.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [grappelli dashboard](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard_setup.html) to make a box with custom links on the admin index.
After installing the dashboard you can use the LinkList to add links.

```
class CustomIndexDashboard(Dashboard):

    def init_with_context(self, context):
        ...
        self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
            _('Links'),
            column=2,
            children=[
                {
                    'title': u'Homepage',
                    'url': '/',
                    'external': False,
                },
            ]
        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a link to the admin title (top left corner) by adding the following to your settings.py:

```
GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = '<a href="/">Homepage</a>'
```

Comment: Simple and works well except that it shows html in the window's title

Comment: @Mark well spotted I've never noticed that before.

Comment: You can try using `'<a href="/">Homepage</a><script>document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML.replace(/\|.*/, "| Site Title")</script>'` but I think you'd be better off looking into overriding grappelli templates.